# How to remove a DynamoDB connection from NoSQL Workbench

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am using a Mac with NoSQL Workbench.

Adding a remote database connection is easy.

However, I cannot find a way to remove a remote connection.

Is there a way to remove connections?

[image]
[image: Remove Connection]

Answer (score 1):

Go to C:\Users\{your account name}\.aws\credentials

Open that file using a text editor, remove the connection from there.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you It did work. But there should be another way through the GUI application